# How to add another person dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing a registration website and there's a part where I need to add people. What I do is when they click on a text bellow the name and last name of the person another two fields (asking the name and the person once again, so it's a copy of the one above) appear. This I do it using the `clone()` method. So let's say the name and last name are inside a div with a class called: "information". And the `<p>` that adds the extra div when contained has an id called: "add". Like this:

```
<div class="information">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"> //it's an array because there's gonna be probably more than one (if they click the "add" text)
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name[]">
</div>
<p id="add">Add another person</p>
```

My javascript (jquery) is the following:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('.information').clone().insertAfter('.information');
});
```

The problem with this is that when you click the add text it copies the first div (and if you wrote something on it, it copies it too). So how can I solve that. Is there any other way to do it? Plus, is there any easy way to make a button to disappear an "information" div (in case the user regrets how many people he wants to add).

Any recommendation is well received.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
Sorry guys. There's something important that I forgot to say. The information class is only displayed if the user click a checkbox (because there's the possibility that they don't wish to add any other person.
So, here is the code for the checkbox:

HTML (above the information class):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="companion" />Companion
```

JQuery:

```
$("#companion").click(function() {
     $(".information").toggle();
     if ($('#companion').is(":checked")) {
        $('#add').show();
     }
     else {
        $('.companion').hide();
        $('.companion').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
```

I clarify this because I tried the examples that you guys show me but when I click the checkbox the information div does not show up.
I should have mention this on my original post. I really sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change it just slightly and do it like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dDHML/2/)**.

This allows you to add people and remove any new one you add while always leaving just the first person.

**HTML**

```
<div id="information">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name[]"> 
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="last_name[]">
</div>
<p id="add">Add another person</p>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#add').click(function() {
    $('#information').clone().find("input:text").val("").end().append('<span class="remove">remove</span>').removeAttr('id').insertBefore('#add');

});
$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});​
```

Comment: You should be able to change your checkbox code to account for my changing your information div from a class to an ID. Try changing any mention of `$(".information")` to `$("#information")`. Here's a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dDHML/3/

Comment: It works perfect except for the remove. I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'. And yes, I'm loading the script AFTER jquery. What could it be?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ah that explains it. `.on()` was added in jQuery 1.7. You can use `.live()` in place of `.on()`, but going forward `.live()` has been deprecated and will go away while `.on()` is what is replacing it, so if possible, update your jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:last` and `:first` selectors, try the following:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    $('.information:first').clone().insertAfter('.information:last');
    $('.information:last').find('input').val('');
});

$('#remove').click(function(){
    if ($('.information').length > 1) {
       $('.information:last').remove()
    }
})
```

```
<p id='remove'>remove<p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnE6Y/1/)

Comment: @fedejp You are welcome, something like this? your code works here, http://jsfiddle.net/SnE6Y/2/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cloning the last div (because there's content inside), I think it would be better to store the contents of .information in a variable (call it "content"). Then on pageload, you can call your "content" and on add, you call up "content".

If you want, you can create a button inside the .information div and give it a click function that removes this instance of the .information div.